# Breeze's errorCallback function is never called

Tags: javascript, breeze, aurelia-breeze

If I call a web API method (which throws an exception) using breeze's executeQuery method (Breeze version is 1.6.3), the errorCallback function is never called.

```
var eq = new breeze.EntityQuery('TestError'); 
manager.executeQuery( 
    eq, 
    function(data) { console.log('success') }, 
    function(err) { console.log('error') }
);
```

this is the api method

```
[HttpGet] 
public void TestError() { 
    throw new Exception("test exception"); 
}
```

nor does it work with what is described [here](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html) (see executeQuery method)

My app uses Aurelia and the aurelia-breeze plugin, and I suppose this problem happens because aurelia-breeze replaces Q with ES6 Promises.
Is it possible to have the errorCallback called anyway? Or am I just doing something wrong?

[Here is my original post on the aurelia-breeze github page](https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze/issues/46)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it (at least I think so), by adding an extra .catch() in an inner Promise in aurelia-breeze's source files. Details [here](https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze/issues/46)